# Using Sequences in clojure macros

Tags: macros, clojure

I am reading data from a yaml file that results in data like this:

```
{:test1 (1 2 3)}
```

I can lookup the key `:test1` and get a `clojure.lang.LazySeq` with the elements `1 2 3`. But when I want to use this data in a macro it gets expanded to a function call and not to a quoted list.

For example:

```
(defmacro mmerge
  [map1 map2]
  `(assoc ~(merge map1 map2) :merged true))

(mmerge {:test1 (1 2 3)} {:test2 (4 5 6)})
```

This gets expanded to:

```
(clojure.core/assoc {:test2 (4 5 6), :test1 (1 2 3)} :merged true)
```

Is there a possibility to somehow get this to work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: why is this a macro?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve the same with a function if you write the map arguments' values as quoted lists:

```clj
(defn mmerge*
  [map1 map2]
  (assoc (merge map1 map2) :merged true))

(mmerge* {:test1 '(1 2 3)} {:test2 '(4 5 6)})
;= {:merged true, :test2 (4 5 6), :test1 (1 2 3)}
```

If you still want a macro, you need to quote the result from the `merge` operation in the form returned by the macro (or as [@fl00r mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26897292/519383) it is absolutely correct if you just quote the lists :P):

```clj
(defmacro mmerge
  [map1 map2]
  `(assoc '~(merge map1 map2) :merged true))
```

Which results in the following macroexpansion:

```clj
(clojure.core/assoc '{:test2 (4 5 6), :test1 (1 2 3)} :merged true)
```